# How and where can I explicitly view the source maps in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find a full answer anywhere.  When viewing a website, the browser must load source maps to enable debugging of the original code.  It's evident that source maps are being used due to the following indication (this example is taken from the typescriptlang.org site:

[image]

At the bottom of the same file, you can see the source map URL comment as follows:

`//# sourceMappingURL=component---src-templates-pages-cheatsheets-tsx-d685670bdc739b0b8cff.js.map`

When using the 'Source Maps Monitor' feature in Edge or the 'Developer Resources' tab in Chrome, you can clearly see that the maps were loaded.

My question is simply -- why aren't the *.map files shown in the Sources overview?  Is there a way to enable this?  Where physically are they so I can manually inspect them?

I tried a workaround that involves downloading the source map files manually by copying the URL from the 'Developer Resources' tab.  But I'm interested in seeing the maps in the 'Sources' tab of DevTools.